# From F-1 to B2 Status

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, f1-visas

I just finished my degree in the US under an F-1 status. During that time I still have my B2/B1 tourist status. I have returned to my home country but want to go back to the US fro vacation, will I be able to just go in using my valid Tourist visa now? Or do I have to do something else??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have more than one US immigration status at a time, and any nonimmigrant status you have ceases when you leave the US.  A nonimmigrant who leaves the US and returns can be readmitted in the same status or a different status depending on the circumstances of the subsequent trip to the US.

You can have more than one nonimmigrant *visa* reflecting different nonimmigrant categories, however, as it seems you do.  A US visa merely allows you to travel to the US in order to apply for admission under the corresponding status.

As a former F-1 nonimmigrant, outside the US and in possession of a valid B-1/B-2 visa, you can travel to the US and apply for admission in B-1 or B-2 status.  The answers to your questions, therefore:

> Will I be able to just go in using my valid tourist visa now?

Yes.

> Or do I have to do something else?

No, you don't have to do anything else.